# How to use definition of convexity to prove

Tags: convex-analysis, linear-programming

Suppose $\lambda$ is a fixed scalar and $A$ is a matrix. Show using the definition of convexity that $\{x|x\in\mathbb{R}^n, Ax = \lambda x\}$ is always a convex set.

I understand that formally the definition of a convex set goes as following:

> $S$ is convex if $x_1, x_2 \in S$, then $x=\lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda)x_2, 0\leq\lambda \leq1$

Comment: You can't even get the definition right, how do you expect us to help you?

Comment: Can you help me get the definition correctly? This is what my textbook is giving me.

Comment: No it is not. The remaining two symbols must have flown to the next page or the next line.

Comment: Is that better?

Comment: Oh, so you didn't include the **whole definition** from your book. No, something is still missing.

Comment: Help me out here.. I only have my notes not my textbook man. No need to be a stifler about it.

Comment: It may help to remember what convex means in the special case of $\Bbb R^2$ and how that then relates to the abstract definition.  A convex region (like a circle or square) is one where for any two points you pick in the region you can draw a line segment between them that is completely within the region.  On the other hand, something that is not convex (like a horseshoe shape) you can find some pair of points whose line segment connecting them leaves the region.  Compare this (*admittedly naive*) interpretation of convexity to the formal definition given below.

Comment: @JMoravitz I wouldn't say that is a naive interpretation of convexity, it is perfectly correct and crystal clear.  That is the definition of convexity.

Comment: @littleO in the very specific case of $\Bbb R^2$ and "line segments" as we are used to them.  In more abstract settings "line segments" between elements doesn't necessarily make sense to talk about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of convex set is

$S$ is convex if $x_1, x_2 \in S$, then $\forall \lambda \in (0,1), x = \lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda)x_2 \color{blue}{\in S}$.

To avoid confusion of notation, let me replace $\lambda$ in previous statement using $\mu$.

$S$ is convex if $x_1, x_2 \in S$, then $\forall \mu \in (0,1), x = \mu x_1 + (1-\mu)x_2 \in S$.

Hence for your case, you are suppose to check if the following is true

If $Ax_1 = \lambda x_1$ and $Ax_2=\lambda x_2$, verify that

$$A(\mu x_1 + (1-\mu) x_2) = \lambda (\mu x_1+(1-\mu )x_2)$$